# Efficiently Update a List of Cursor and insert into collection in Casbah

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

I am querying a collection and I want to update the results.

I want to update a field and let the remaining fields untouched.

I have entries with "filename" and "projectId" as keys

In this case I am doing:

```
val olderFiles = conn.find(query ++ ("filename" -> filename) ++ ("projectId" -> file.projectId))
val updatedFiles = olderFiles.map{cursor =>
            cursor.put("newField",field)
            cursor
          }

updatedFiles.foreach(conn += _)
```

However this is slow.
How do I update a list of objects in a more efficient manner?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
conn.update(query ++ ("filename" -> filename) ++ ("projectId" -> projectId),$set ("field" -> field),false,true)
```

This updates every entry that is found by that query.

PS: For future [reference](http://xkcd.com/979/), if there is a list of fields (.e.g. in this case filenames), instead of using a foreach in these fields and create N queries, one can do this:

```
"filename" $in Array(fieldList:_*)
```